# Using PIR 3.3 V 0.33 mA to drive 12V 4A valve coil

Tags: transistors, mosfet, solenoid, solenoid-valve, pir

I've been looking at ways to drive a 4 A, 12 V solenoid valve from a tiny, 3.3 V, 0.33 mA (max) current output from a PIR module.

Whatever I try (MOSFETs, transistors etc), there never seems to be enough current or voltage from the PIR unit to drive enough current through the load.

The PIR has 3 connections: 0 V, 12 V and output.

Can anyone suggest a suitable MOSFET I could use, or an alternative circuit?

Comment: Which PIR module works at 3.3V? Show make, model, at the very least.

Comment: We don't really need that when we know the output specs...

Comment: I think you mean "to control ..." rather than "to drive..."

Answer (score 1):

"Normal" mosfets wont work in this application. What you are looking for is a so called "Logic Level" fet. The devices you have likely tried have a typical gate-source voltage of 8 or so volts to get them to fully turn on. Logic level fets are far less common and and you will likely have to order one from an online supplier. [IPP60R385CPXK from Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-Technologies/IPP60R385CPXK/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2FWiwqrrLOKvP1J7djlJBN6HLI%3D) would work as its Vgs is only 3v.

Answer (score 0):

- example 3V min PIR Analog sensor : Panasonic [EKMC1601111](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/panasonic-electric-works/EKMC1601111/255-3074-ND/2601868?WT.srch=1&mkwid=sKDypBYFx&pcrid=87194119145&pkw=_cat%3Asensors&pmt=b&pdv=c)
- with suggested one shot solenoid or relay driver from PIR sensor.
- Choose "Logic Level" MOSFET Driver with RdsOn or BJT as shown from One Shot and power source ESR to be < ~2% of coil DCR for good efficiency, load regulation and low heat loss. must not interfere with 3.3V supply and ground return, otherwise hysteresis effects or false switching may be seen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are opto isolators that will drive with very small currents.  I had an application that was 3.3Vdc @ < 1mA.  In that case IXYS's CPC1301 was suitable.  It might be possible to use it or a similar opto in your application.